# iPhone X support required only launch image or all image?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, ios11, iphone-x

I'm working in an old iOS/Objective-C project.
To support my app in iPhone X, I've added iPhone X launch image in my project, and it seems my app is supporting full screen in iPhone X.

So, Is it necessary (strongly) to upgrade all graphics to 3X in order to support iPhone X design? or just launch image is fine to get my app approved from Apple?

Are there any chances to get my app **rejected**, if I **only add launch image for iPhone X, and keep all assets in 2X size??**

Comment: 3x is better so that your image of 2x won't get pixelated on 3x...

Comment: Just FYI, adding 3x images also means you add support for iPhone 6+, 6s+, 7+ and 8+

Comment: Can I get my app rejected, If I only add launch image for iPhone X, and keep all assets in 2X size??